# order of android rotation matrix conversion

Tags: android, rotation

android uses the following code to calculate rotation matrix:

```
    float Ax = gravity[0];
    float Ay = gravity[1];
    float Az = gravity[2];
    final float Ex = geomagnetic[0];
    final float Ey = geomagnetic[1];
    final float Ez = geomagnetic[2];
    float Hx = Ey*Az - Ez*Ay;
    float Hy = Ez*Ax - Ex*Az;
    float Hz = Ex*Ay - Ey*Ax;
    final float normH = (float)Math.sqrt(Hx*Hx + Hy*Hy + Hz*Hz);
    if (normH < 0.1f) {
        // device is close to free fall (or in space?), or close to
        // magnetic north pole. Typical values are  > 100.
        return false;
    }
    final float invH = 1.0f / normH;
    Hx *= invH;
    Hy *= invH;
    Hz *= invH;
    final float invA = 1.0f / (float)Math.sqrt(Ax*Ax + Ay*Ay + Az*Az);
    Ax *= invA;
    Ay *= invA;
    Az *= invA;
    final float Mx = Ay*Hz - Az*Hy;
    final float My = Az*Hx - Ax*Hz;
    final float Mz = Ax*Hy - Ay*Hx;
    if (R != null) {
        if (R.length == 9) {
            R[0] = Hx;     R[1] = Hy;     R[2] = Hz;
            R[3] = Mx;     R[4] = My;     R[5] = Mz;
            R[6] = Ax;     R[7] = Ay;     R[8] = Az;
        } else if (R.length == 16) {
            R[0]  = Hx;    R[1]  = Hy;    R[2]  = Hz;   R[3]  = 0;
            R[4]  = Mx;    R[5]  = My;    R[6]  = Mz;   R[7]  = 0;
            R[8]  = Ax;    R[9]  = Ay;    R[10] = Az;   R[11] = 0;
            R[12] = 0;     R[13] = 0;     R[14] = 0;    R[15] = 1;
        }
    }
```

i would like to know what is the logic behind this
also, what is the order of rotation used?
i want to correct the rotation using the rotation matrix. so the order of calculation by android is important.

Comment: What do you mean correct the rotation?  

The rotation is given by the rotation matrix itself based on the accelerometer and magnetometer values.  So I don't know what you'd be correcting

Comment: im taking a picture with a certain roll and pitch. android gives me the roll and pitch angles. i want to know in which order i have to roll it back and pitch it back(using rotation matrices).

Comment: R=RX * RY * RZ or R= RX * RZ * RY and so on.if rotation matrix is calculated in the first order, then i need to apply a RZ-1 * RY-1 * RX-1 to get the right correction. i need to know the order in which R is calculated by android for that.

Comment: You can just take the inverse of R instead of doing all three of them.

Comment: **R=RX*RY*RZ
-->R*R-1=RX*RY*RZ*RZ-1*RY-1*RZ-1=I**

Comment: there is the problem. i want to correct only two of the angles.

Comment: http://www.cms.livjm.ac.uk/pgnet2012/Proceedings/Papers/1569603133.pdf

Comment: in the link i provided, they have calculated R using cos and sin terms. is there an equivalent way of explaining this?

Comment: I see.  Well I'm not sure how they are doing it exactly because they are using both sensors.  It appears to not be so simple as Rx*Ry*Rz.  You could also take the gravity vector from the accelerometer to figure out the rotation matrices yourself.

Comment: can you tell me how to calculate rotation matrix using the sensors? not the android way haha!

Comment: Sitting flat, the accelerometer vector will point straight up.  The rotation matrices are the linear transformations that take you from the straight up accelerometer vector to the actual accelerometer vector received by the sensor.

Answer (score 1):

Android assumes the gravity parameter is a vector lying on the world sky axis. That is if (**w_1**, **w_2**, **w_3**) is the world basis where **w_1** is a unit vector pointing East, **w_2** is a unit vector pointing North and **w_3** is a vector pointing toward the sky, then the gravity parameter is a vector that is a multiple of **w_3**. Therefore the normalize of the gravity parameter is **w_3**.
Also, the code assume the geomagnetic field parameter is a vector lying on the plane spanned by **w_2** and **w_3** Thus the cross product of the normalize geomagnetic field parameter and the normalize gravity parameter is a unit vector orthogonal to the plane spanned by **w_2** and **w_3**. Therefore this product is just **w_1**.
Now the cross product of **w_3** and **w_1** is **w_2**. Thus you get the change of basis from the device coordinate to the world coordinate.
I do not understand what do you mean by "the order of rotation used" and thus cannot answer that question.